# Xampp. Php script displays a blank page!

Tags: php, xampp, screen-scraping

The php script is calling four functions that scrape different websites for data.

```
$returnData[0]=getWebsite1Data($description);
$returnData[1]=getWebsite2Data($description);
$returnData[2]=getWebsite3Data($description);
$returnData[3]=getWebsite4Data($description);
```

The script displays the web-page correctly if I disable the call to any one random function.

That makes me think its a resource problem. If it is a resource problem how do I correct it in Xampp. I've tried unsetting the variables but that didn't work either.

Comment: Check your web server logs for errors.

Comment: Well from this small code sample it is not easy to figure where the problem is. Maybe you can provide more code?

Comment: I have this error in the logs: 

'child process exited with status 3221225477' . 

I looked it up on google and applied some of the solution but still doesn't work.

Comment: Here's a strange thing. If I let one of the functions echo the html to the browser then the module works correctly for all the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure Error Reporting is set high enough in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Check your phpinfo and see what your "memory_limit" is. Try doubling it in your php.ini.